# Loading Content Values from JSON

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to load Content Values into a database. The code here works:

```
private void processTable(final JsonReader tableReader, final ModelLoader loader) throws IOException
    {
        tableReader.beginArray();
        while (tableReader.hasNext()) {
            String id = loader.getIdColumnName();
            final ContentValues cv = loader.parseModel(tableReader);

            persistData(loader.getTableName(),id, cv);
        }
        tableReader.endArray();
    }
```

However, when I add an additional part into it, it fails.

```
private void processTable(final JsonReader tableReader, final ModelLoader loader) throws IOException
    {
        tableReader.beginArray();
        while (tableReader.hasNext()) {
            String id = loader.getIdColumnName();
            final ContentValues cv = loader.parseModel(tableReader);

            if (loader.getModelType() == Filter.LOADER.getModelType())                  //Checks to see if the filter sub arrays are there
            {
                while(tableReader.hasNext()) 
                {
                    String name = "";
                    try{
                        tableReader.
                        name = tableReader.nextName();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    tableReader.skipValue();
                    continue;
                    }
                    if (name.equals("ImageOverlays"))
                        processTable(tableReader, mLoader.getSpecificLoader("ImageOverlays"));
                    else if (name.equals("ColorOverlays"))
                        processTable(tableReader, mLoader.getSpecificLoader("ColorOverlays"));
                }
            }

            persistData(loader.getTableName(),id, cv);
        }
        tableReader.endArray();
    }
```

The purpose of the additional code is to get a particular item from the Filters and then process them. When I use this code, I don't even get any values for the Filters which I used to before.

I think that me skipping the values is somehow screwing up the ContentValues cv that I declare before it.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why are you having _while (tableReader.hasNext())_ two times?
Having "hasNext()" two times that too inside a loop of another is bad way of programming...

Comment: The interior while loop is only accessed when I need to iterate through the Filter. The top one iterates through all my objects in the JSON.

Comment: But your interior loop will skip the objects to be processed from the external and also check with some logs in catch statement if you are getting any exception if yes then its obvious that all the objects will be skipped from parsing...

Comment: Ah, I'm an idiot. I didn't think that the Content Values I generated before I did that would be affected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Its your Interior loop causing the problem which is skipping the JSON Objects that have to be parsed...

And Yeah the Content Values as you mentioned in the comments are not valid by the time you reach the end of the loop.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to get to the Overlays that don't screw everything up?

Comment: ModelLoader and JsonReader are two different objects so you have to logically analyze the dependencies before iterating through each object.

I assume the outer while loop is unnecessary in your case...

Try figuring out the possibilities with just a single loop, inner loop as recommended...